# Django logon SSO through Active Directory without any actions with DC server

Tags: django, active-directory, single-sign-on

We are moving from Java-GWT-Tomcat on Python-Django-Apache. We have Active Directory and SSO mechanism as getting users member groups info. It's made with [Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) and it's doesn't require any server-side Kerberos keytab or adding service account in  AD. Is there any way to do this with Python-Django-Apache?